# How to remove the interior points of an image with skimage?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm trying to port some MATLAB code that uses `bwmorph(image,'remove')`.

Basically this takes a BW image and removes any point (change white to black) that has 4 white neighbors.

Is there something similar in skimage? I looked here, but could not find anything: https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.morphology.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for `bwmorph(..., 'remove')`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) (which is rather poorly named), it looks like it is simply doing:

```py
from skimage.morphology import erosion

removed = image - erosion(image)
```